# How can I do this more elegantly?

Tags: c++, geometry

I have a 2D point A inside the [0,1]² square.

The square is divided into 9 subsquares (of equal dimensions)
http://www.noelshack.com/2015-23-1433689273-capture.png

I want to know which subsquare the point A belongs to.

I can do a if elseif else on the first coordinate, then inside each branch, another if else if else on the second coordinate.

There is a lot of code repeating (the check on the second coordinate)

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Why the downvotes ? I gave all the informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is, it is not clear what your 2D point is, what you want the sub-square value as, etc. So a definitive answer is difficult. But anyway, I will make some assumptions and see if I am right about what you are asking...

---

Assuming you had a point A with a coordinate such as:

```
float point[2] = {0.1224, 0.4553}
```

Then to work out where it is inside the square you can do some simple maths:

```
float x = point[0] * 3;
float y = point[1] * 3; //Multiply both by 3
int xIdx = floor(x);
int yIdx = floor(y); //Floor the result - this gives a number 0 to 2
int cell = yIdx * 3 + xIdx + 1; // Calculate the cell index (based on your diagram)
```

Now you could generalise this for any point - for example the point might be (1.23343, 2.6768) - by simply removing the integer part from the point - leaving a number between 0 and 1. The integer part would be the super cell, and the fractional part would be converted into the sub cell as above.

Comment: Thank you, your answer matches exactly what I wanted to know and I see why it works. My 2D point was a simple class with accessors for x and y, and I want the sub-square value to be from 1 to 9 as shown in the diagram